# How to create asymmetric keys in C# because of limited exponent size?

Tags: c#, encryption, biginteger

I am creating a little software to encrypt and decrypt data using asymmetric keys.

The problem is, I am coding in C# and even if I use  :

```
 BigInteger.Pow(BigIntenger myNumber, int myExponent);
```

The exponent is an "int" and my value is to big for an int.

Just to quickly explain and to be sure I am not doing any mistake, you have to use big numbers to make it more difficult to decrypt without having the private key.

So I have

- N = P * Q
- P and Q are both prime numbers.
- M = (P-1)+(Q-1)
- C is a prime number with M
- Then find U with : C×U+M×V=1

**Public key (N,C).**

**Private key (U,N).**

For example you want to encrypt : "Bonjour !" to UTF8.

You will have :

B⇔66 / o⇔111 / n⇔110 / j⇔106 / o⇔111 / u⇔117 / r⇔114 / (espace)⇔32 / !⇔33

Then raise each numbers to the power of C and modulo N.

> Ex : valueOfB = (66^C)%N.

Now your message is encrypted.

If you want to decrypt it, you have to multiply each value by exponent U and modulo N.

> Ex : (valueOfB^U)%N

So I can do this only if I use small number because I will have a small U value that fit with a "int" but it's not secure, how can I do this with a big U like BigInteger and not int ?

Comment: You might want to look here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43272/why-is-writing-your-own-encryption-discouraged, and another one: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: @PeterB: At some point somebody has got to write the code behind the libraries which mean other people do not need to do things again. So I don't think the answers is just to say don't bother doing it - there are plenty of reasons to want to do this sort of thing - for fun, for the experience of writing encryption code, ... I have written my own code for JPG & MP3 encryption/decryption - I would never use it in production code but it was fun to do.

Comment: In your description of the procedure you write _"Then each number have to be multiplied by exponent C and modulo N."_ but the code you show raises the number to the power of C - which of these is correct? If you are multiplying then BigInteger allows two BigIntegers to be multiplied together.

Comment: Thank you PaulF, I didn't know how to say it correctly, indeed it's "raise the number to the power of C" like in the example :) !

Comment: Do not use `a^b`, use `(a^b)%c` instead: [`ModPow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.modpow)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't know this function, I think that could be the solution. I still have issues with my values so I can't confirm, but it looks like it's doing what I need !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigInteger.Pow` of a BigInteger would be a massively complicated number.

Binary multiplication has the property that (roughly speaking) multiplying an `n`-bit number by an `m`-bit number produces an approximately `(n+m)`-bit answer.

```
10 * 4096 = 0b1010 * 0b1_0000_0000_0000  (4 bits, 13 bits)
40960 = 0b1010_0000_0000_0000 (16 bits)

16 * 4096 = 0b1_0000 * 0b1_0000_0000_0000  (5 bits, 13 bits)
65536 = 0b1_0000_0000_0000_0000 (17 bits)

15 * 4095 = 0b1111 * 0b1111_1111_1111 (4 bits, 12 bits)
61425 = 0b1110_1111_1111_0001 (16 bits)
```

Since exponentiation is repeated multiplication, and multiplication is repeated addition, we can see that raising a 1024-bit number to the power of a 512-bit number would produce an answer in the realm of 1024*512 bits (524288 bits, 65536 bytes).

But you're then going to follow it up with a modulus operation, bringing it back down the realm of a 1024-bit number.  That's pretty wasteful.

Thankfully, algorithms exist for doing efficient [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).  Double thankfully for you, .NET went ahead and wrote that for you.

What you're looking for is

```
valueOfB = BigInteger.ModPow(66, U, N);
```

Comment: Someone gave me this function in the comment just above but thank you for the explanation :) ! I can mark this question as solve.